# Sneaker bot checkout process

Tags: python

hi every one im newbie in programing.and i need help to work my code i need to post this in formation to this web site https://live.adyen.com/hpp/completeCard.shtml.but i get error pls help...

```
import requests

headers = {"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image   /apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
       "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
       "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
       "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
       "Connection": "keep-alive",
       "Content-Length": "5185",
       "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
       "Host": "live.adyen.com",
       "Origin": "https://live.adyen.com",
       "Referer": "https://live.adyen.com/hpp/pay.shtml",
       "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
       "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
       "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
       "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
       "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
       "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
       "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36"}

payload = {"card.cardNumber": "4001 0200 0000 0009",
       "card.cardHolderName": "Juan Tamad",
       "card.expiryMonth": "03",
       "card.expiryYear": "2030",
       "card.cvcCode": "737"}

r = requests.post("https://live.adyen.com/hpp/completeCard.shtml/post", headers=headers, data=payload)
```

print(r.text)

i got this error

There was a problem displaying this page. Please try again later, or verify your input on the previous page

Comment: please paste the error logs or atleast describe what is the error.